# Trouble with Inheritance c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I seem to be having some trouble with inheritance. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong, but I believe that it is calling the classes incorrectly. I'm still really new to inheritance so I'm sure there are areas that I got wrong in it. It's supposed to call something from each class and make a phrase at the end, but it dosen't seem to be working. It is also supposed to override the previous Show Address.

```
class DSC
{
    private string schoolName { get; set; }


    string schoolName = "DSC";

    public virtual string ShowAddress();

    { return " 1420 W. Highway Blvd., Orlando, Florida 33268 "}        
}


class Campus
{
    private string campusName { get; set; }


    public string campusName
    {
        get
        {
            return campusName;
        }
        set
        {
            campusName = value;
        }

        public Campus(string cName);


    public virtual string ShowAddress()
    { return "1843 Bob Blvd., Orlando, Florida 33268"; }
    public string Departments()
    { return "Computer Scinece Department, Emergency Care Department, Police Academy"; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Campus atc = new Campus("Advanced Technology College");
        Console.WriteLine(atc.ToString());
    }
}
```

What the Output is supposed to be

```
Daytona State College Advanced Technology College 
    is located at  1843 Bob Blvd., Orlando, Florida 33268, 
    it has Computer Scinece Department, Emergency Care Department,  Police Academy
```

Comment: what goes wrong, what output do you get?

Comment: Not that this deals with inheritance.. but in your Campus class, you have two properties called `campusName`.. I think you're trying to do a field and then the property, not two separate properties with the same name.

Comment: also you do not have a ToString method on your class, so you will just get a general purpose object message

Comment: .. and there's no inheritance in this code

Comment: Doesn't look like the code would even compile, let alone produce the expected output.

Comment: Please, do post code that actually compiles!

Comment: @stuartd That's what I'm trying to figure out. I'm still new to inheritance and can't seem to figure out what to do. I would appreciate if someone explained what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, we do not only see no inheritance but also we have no clue where you want to have any inheritance. Seems you just read the word and want us to explain its meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the getter and setter of your private campusName and rename your public campusName to CampusName.

Add following code in your Campus class

```
public override string ToString()
{
  return CampusName() + "\n is located at " + ShowAddress() + "\n it has " + Departments();
}
```

You should write a base School class

```
public class School
{
  private string schoolName;
  private string address;

  public string SchoolName
  {
     get
     {
       return schoolName;
     }
     set
     {
       schoolName = value;
     }
  }

  // same game with address
}
```

After that you only have to inherit ....

```
public Campus : School
{
   // override or add methods 
}
```

Comment: It tells me that 'Campus' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 argument.

Comment: You need that constructor-> public Campus(string campus) { schoolName = campus;}

Comment: Adding that code and moving some of the other code around fixed the problem. Thank-you for your help.